# Making asynchronous api call resulting unexpected responses but while doing synchronous returns expected response

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, asynchronous, retrofit2.6

Hi I am making synchronous API call using retrofit one by one these APIs return results successfully. But while I am trying to asynchronously the APIs sometimes return exact response but sometimes an error.
We are passing auth_key in the header. So we can't figure out the issue here.

For managing currently, I am making API calls one after another. But this is n't the right way to handle this.

Frontend tech used:Android,Java
Backend tech used: Java Springboot

Comment: Please add [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: what kind of error occur? is it server error?

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov yes sometimes returns  401 , unauthorised access which is set to be returned if auth_key in header is invalid. but auth_key is passing in header which is clearly visible in logger.

Comment: if the apis call one by one then it is returning correct response